# Arrays are passed as strings to custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created cusotm directive with isolated scope. But when I'm passing to my directive variable of type Array i'm getting String inside directive.

My directive:

```
angular.module('my.directives')
    .directive('testDirective', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                myArray: '@'
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                alert("Is arr: " + angular.isArray($scope.myArray)); // outputs false                 
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="currentObject in list">
    <div test-directive my-array="{{currentObject.arrayOfNumbers}}"></div>
</div>
```

Variable `currentObject.arrayOfNumbers` is 100% of type array - I checked it in my controller using `angular.isArray` method, but when passing it inside directive I'm getting just a string.

I.e. if

```
currentObject.arrayOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4]
```

then inside directive I have exactly same string: `"[1,2,3,4]"`

Comment: change `@` to `=` and `{{currentObject.arrayOfNumbers}}` to `currentObject.arrayOfNumbers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are not using 2-way binding correctly. You are setting the text for the attribute `my-array` by doing :-

```
<div test-directive my-array="{{currentObject.arrayOfNumbers}}"></div>
```

change it to:-

```
<div test-directive my-array="currentObject.arrayOfNumbers"></div>
```

So that the object will be bound correctly to the 2 way bound scope variable in the directive.

and change  `myArray: '@'` to  `myArray: '='` :-

If you are doing `myArray:'@'` which is text binding then do `JSON.parse($scope.myArray)` or `$scope.$eval($scope.myArray))`

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDzWtJ?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks. But your solution worked for me only after I changed `'@'` to `'='`. What is problem?

Comment: @MyTitle Sorry i did not see that. I assumed you were using '=' If you are using `@` then just do: `JSON.parse($scope.myArray)` or `angular.toObject($scope.myArray)`. But it wont be 2-way binding anymore.